# Activity reboots from Memory after choosing picture using StartActivityForResult()

Tags: android, image, mvvmcross

I'm working on a mvvmcross android project,
 And I need to select a picture from gallery
,but as I call StartActivityForResults() in my view, the activity reboots and the first page is shown again.

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            ResourceId = Resource.Layout.StayView;
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            int PickImageId = 1000;
            Intent = new Intent();
            Intent.SetType("image/*");
            Intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
            StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(Intent, "Select Picture"), PickImageId);
            //MvxInternalStartActivityForResult(Intent, 3001);
         }
```

I already have read this,but couldn't figure how to prevent activity from rebooting :

> "The problem is that the instance of the Activity that calls
>   StartActivityForResult is not necessarily the same instance that
>   receives OnActivityResult - instead Android can have called
>   onSaveInstanceState, killed your Activity and then restarted a new
>   instance (it can even have killed you entire app in the meantime too).
>   I've seen this happen in real apps when, for example, I've used
>   StartActivityForResult to get a picture from the camera. Because the
>   camera can use a lot of RAM, Android can sometimes boot the activity
>   from memory and then restart it (using the saved instance state
>   bundle) after the picture is chosen. The problem here is that private
>   Action onActivityResultHandler is hard to serialise!
>   (This is also the reason Xamarin.Mobile no longer supports the old
>   Task API for its picture taking). If you want to test this scenario,
>   you can force this to happen on Android 4 devices using the developer
>   setting 'do not keep activities'"

I was hoping to find a workaround for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/MvvmCross-plugins#picturechooser

> Note: Using this interface well on Android is very difficult.
>
> The reason for this is because of Android's Activity lifecyle. The
>   Android lifecycle means that the image that may be returned to a
>   different View and ViewModel than the one that requested it. This is
>   partly because camera apps generally use a lot of RAM (raw camera
>   images are large files) - so while th camera app is capturing you
>   image, then Android may look to free up additional RAM by killing your
>   app's Activity.
>
> If you want to use this  IMvxPictureChooserTask  effectively and
>   reliably on Android then you really need to call this API via a
>   service class, to use Messaging to pass the returned message back to a
>   ViewModel and to implement 'tombstoning' support for that ViewModel.

Alternatively, you can always take the source code for the plugin - https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/3.2/Plugins/Cirrious/PictureChooser/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.PictureChooser.Droid - and create your own variant that works in your app